# what are the differences between 'NgChartModule' and 'chartModues'?

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

If I want to generate bargraphs, pie charts and doughnutcharts which module should be import?

```
'''
import { NgChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
or
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the version of Chart.js (and Ng2Charts) you are using.

When you are using V2 of Chart.js (and Ng2Charts) you need to import `ChartsModule`.
When you are using V3 of Chart.js (and Ng2Charts) you need to import `NgChartsModule` .